# What is the difference between null and isEmpty() in queue

Tags: java, null, queue, is-empty

[image]

What the difference between using `q != null` and `!q.isEmpty()`?
when I used q!=null in the following code, it's not going to be compiled. But !q.isEmpty() works pretty well.

java

```
Queue<TreeNode[]> q=new LinkedList<>();
q.add(new TreeNode[]{t1, t2});
while(q!=null){          // is not complied
    TreeNode[] t=q.remove();

    if(t[0]==null || t[1]==null) continue;

    t[0].val+=t[1].val;

    if(t[0].left==null) t[0].left=t[1].left;
    else q.add(new TreeNode[]{t[0].left, t[1].left});

    if(t[0].right==null) t[0].right=t[1].right;
    else q.add(new TreeNode[]{t[0].right, t[1].right});
}
```

Comment: What compilation error are you given? `while (q != null)` should compile (although it makes no sense at all)

Comment: But it looks like your main problem is that you don't understand the Java concept of null -- please check out the duplicate for information on this

Comment: The error pointed to the line "TreeNode[] t=q.remove();"   , showing NoSuchElementException

Comment: Your statements don't make sense as you're in the question stating that the code won't compile, but in comments state that it is throwing an exception, meaning that the code is in fact compiling and running but then throwing an exception. This is all very confusing I'm afraid.

Comment: But on the other hand it makes sense that an exception will be thrown if you try to remove an element from an empty collection. This has nothing to do with a compilation problem and you'd best read up on the the difference between these two things.

Answer (score 1):

'q' will never be null because you already instantiated it with `new LinkedList` so there will result in an infinite loop. So, in your example, you have to check if the list is empty. But it should compile

Comment: I agree with the instantiation one. But it's not compiled and could you please look at the pic I just attached? It shows the error. Thanks

Comment: @CaraJiang: ***again*** that is not a compilation error

Comment: I agreed with Hovercraft. There is an exception and not a compilation error.

Comment: Santiago, if you want to notify Cara that you are commenting to her, then prepend your comment with an `@` symbol just before the concatenated user name who you want to notify, for example: @CaraJiang

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: ok, thxs for the suggestion!